# SQL Server case when charindex

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax-error, case

I am trying to get this case when statement to work in SQL Server 2008 R2. It keeps saying the '>' symbol is invalid in the case when statement for the `CHARINDEX` part.

```
select 
   count(r.id) as request, 
   case r.servicelayer
      when null then r.topic + '/IAL'
      when '' then r.topic + '/IAL'
      when CHARINDEX('/rssfeed1234/georss/SomMobile', i.URI_STEM) ***>*** 0 then 'Som Mobile'
      else r.topic + '/' + r.servicelayer
    end as [layername]
from iis_metrics.tblReportData as r
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're mixing two different ways of using `CASE` in an invalid way.

**Either** you use `CASE (some column name)` and then you **must** use just some condition that applies **to that column**. This is OK in the first two clauses: `WHEN NULL` or `WHEN ''`  (this is sort of a "short hand" for using `WHEN .. IS NULL` or `WHEN ... = ''` - but if you start using this "short hand" notation, you need to use it in **all** your `WHEN` clauses)

But in this case, you **cannot** suddenly have a complete expression in your `WHEN....` clause as you're trying in your third clause.

This is the **OR** version: you can also use just `CASE` and then each  `WHEN` clause has a complete expression - try this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN r.servicelayer IS NULL THEN r.topic + '/IAL'
  WHEN r.servicelayer = '' THEN r.topic + '/IAL'
  WHEN CHARINDEX('/rssfeed1234/georss/SomMobile', i.URI_STEM) > 0 THEN 'Som Mobile'
  ELSE r.topic + '/' + r.servicelayer
END AS [layername]
```

This should now work - each of your `WHEN` clauses contains a **complete expression** and thus this `CASE` statement is valid.